# iOS Change color of label affected by UIVibrancyEffect

Tags: ios, uitableview, uivisualeffectview, uiblureffect, uivibrancyeffect

Is there a way to somehow affect the color of a label which is under vibrancy effect or at least bring some contrast by setting some tint/alpha/background/whatever properties? As you can see below, in my case the vibrancy created almost unreadable text...

[image]

Comment: At least OS X has something I want for iOS, according to their HIG https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/OSXHIGuidelines/ColorTypography.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20000957-CH13-SW1

Comment: have you tired choosing different blur-styles for the blurred layer and for the vibrancy? I had the same problem and I set the vibrancy _extra light_, the blurred layer was _light_ only; and I had no issue with the texts' readability.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When I went through 2014 WWDC video I found at least some way to affect the appearance of the vibrancy. You can set the background color of the **original blur view's contentView** like this:

```
blurView.contentView.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:0 green:0 blue:0 alpha:0.01];
```

which will unfortunately also affect the whole blur (by tinting) on which the vibrancy was based. But at least the text is much more readable after that.

Answer (score 0):

Yes u can. To render vibrant text, create a UILabel and add it to the vibrancy UIVisualEffectView's contentView. The color of the UILabel does not affect its appearance.

Go through the following link for demo project.
https://github.com/ide/UIVisualEffects

Comment: I already created a vibrant text, the problem was that it is almost unreadable, as you can see in the image above. I wanted to fix that.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think that what you're asking for is doable, but I had a similar problem and [this link](https://www.omnigroup.com/developer/how-to-make-text-in-a-uivisualeffectview-readable-on-any-background) helped me improve my design.